# How to keep Maven integration tests isolated from each other?

Tags: java, database, maven, integration-testing

I have multiple Maven integration tests that are updating the the state of the database, which could create conflicts between these tests. I was wondering if there is a way to isolate these integration tests by leveraging Maven phases or any other approach? Ideally, I would like to have a way to run database migrations before every integration test class. I am using Flyway as the migration tool for my PostgreSQL database and I am using JUnit 4.12. The migrations that I am running are basically creating and populating tables with data for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using `flyway-core`. Basically I ended up doing the following inside each of the test classes:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void migrateDB(){
    Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure().dataSource(url, user, password).load();
    flyway.clean();
    flyway.migrate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Junit has `@Before` and `@After` annotations to let it invoke methods before and after each test class.

Those methods are then responsible for bringing the database into a known state before each test.

Comment: What's the best way to ensure running database migration scripts using the `@Before` and `@After` annotations

Comment: Database migration scripts should in my opinion happen before integration tests are started (you are using a framework, right?) and the java methods should only be responsible for resetting the tables to a known state.

Comment: I see, yes I am using Flyway to run the migrations before the integration tests are started with Maven. Would you recommend using Flyway tools also to reset the tables from the java methods?

Comment: I am not familiar enough with flyway to answer that. You probably need something that can delete all rows and insert known test data.

Answer (score 0):

Responsibilities of Maven is to run tests one by one on **integration-tests** phase, and check results on **verify**. It also able to prepare/shutdown environment. Check [failsafe plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/).

And all isolation between tests is a responsibility of a test framework you use (JUnit, TestNG, Cucumber, etc.).

Comment: Is it possible with these test frameworks to enforce running database migrations before each integration test class to bring the database back to a known state?

Comment: Yes, each of these frameworks has `@Before`. But it is not clear from the question what exactly test frameworks you use and which kind of migration you want to run, all I can say that it is not a responsibility of maven. I would suggest you to ask another, more detailed question with your situation.

Comment: Sorry, I added more details to the question. I am using Flyway and JUnit 4.12. The migrations that I am running are basically creating and populating tables with data for testing.